# SQL Statement with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me with this statement?
I have three tables, `tracks`, `tags` and the pivot table `tag_track`.

`tags` contains music categories and constraints on the pace of the music in beats per minute (bpm).
`tracks` contains all the tracks with fields like title, artist and so on.
`tag_track` is a pivot for `tag_id` and `track_id`.

In this statement I would like to grab all columns of the `tracks` table that have a record in the `tag_track`-table for a certain category. F.ex. music with `id=1` is for running. I would then like to get all tracks for running, within the corresponding bpm-range.

And so I write the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tracks A
INNER JOIN tag_track B ON A.id=B.track_id AND B.tag_id=1
INNER JOIN tags C ON A.bpm >= C.bpm_min AND A.bpm <= C.bpm_max
ORDER BY A.bpm ASC
```

Which works fine for running, which has `id=1`. But as soon as I change to `id=2`, for some reason the bpm constraints for running (`id=1`) are still in effect, and then no tracks are returned.

So the problem is in the third line,

`INNER JOIN tags C ON A.bpm >= C.bpm_min AND A.bpm <= C.bpm_max`

How can I make this line take the bpm constraints for the correct `B.tag_id` or `C.id`?

Comment: could you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ with data set

Answer (score 0):

If `B.tag_id` should be equal to `C.id`, then you can include it in the join, as below:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tracks A
INNER JOIN tag_track B ON A.id=B.track_id AND B.tag_id=1
INNER JOIN tags C ON A.bpm >= C.bpm_min AND A.bpm <= C.bpm_max AND B.tag_id = C.id
ORDER BY A.bpm ASC;
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Again I get a result if B.tag_id=1 but not if B.tag_id=2, even though there are lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it another way...

```
SELECT * FROM tracks A
INNER JOIN tag_track B ON A.id=B.track_id AND B.tag_id=1
WHERE A.bpm > (insert bpm min here) AND A.bpm < (insert bpm max here)
ORDER BY A.bpm ASC
```

This works perfectly.